# C# WPF: Complex Shape objects on a Canvas? MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

This is more of a "Is it possible (with a reasonable amount of time and work)" than a "how exactly is it possible" question. I'm getting into WPF at the moment and am interested in graphical applications in an MVVM approach. In the meaning of an ms-paint like application. Now I see that and how I can draw e.g. a ractangle on a canvas, store those rectangles in a list etc.
But I am wondering if I can do that more advanced. For example extend the rectangle so I can give it more infos (I can't extend the rectangle itself since it's a sealed class), have existing shapes on the canvas able to drag them around, make the shapes complex (e.g. I double click one to open a new Window that represents the "inside" of that shape) etc.

Is such an application possible with a reasonable amount of work and time in WPF or would I rather use some different library/framework for this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, It is possible, Actually, you are listing [CAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-aided_design) specifications, In fact, I work on this type of technology, so I'll suggest you some resources to have a clue..

1. Take a look at [this project](https://github.com/JanusTida/Tida.CAD)(`WPF`, 2D)

[image]

2. And [this one](https://github.com/Macad3D/Macad3D)(`WPF`, 3D)

[image]

3. And [this one](https://github.com/CADproject/Editor)(`WPF`, 2D)

[image]

4. The previous projects are `WPF`-based, also, you might host a `WinForm` control in your WPF app, take a look at [this one](https://github.com/oozcitak/SimpleCad)(`WinForms`, 2D)

[image]

---

If you change the specification a bit and say: "I don't want to edit the drawings on the canvas", then you could go with this option: convert your shapes to `PathFigureCollection` and `EllipseGeometry` objects, then construct `Path`s from these objects and add the `Path`s to the `Canvas`, this is a pure `WPF` approach. Indeed, you can add traditinal controls like `TextBlock`s as children to your `Canvas`, I have done such one like this..

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks you! I will take a closer look at those projects you linked, that should actually help a lot, thank you!